# Migrate Hibernate 5.2 to JPA 2.1

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, jakarta-ee, persistence

I want to remove direct Hibernate references  from my Java EE 7 server application so that I will not have a compile-time dependency on hibernate-core in the future. As a replacement, I want to use the plain JPA API.

So far, I figured out that `org.hibernate.annotations.Cascade` and `org.hibernate.annotations.CascadeType` can be mostly transferred to the cascade-parameter of JPA's `@ManyToOne` or `@OneToMany`.
Also, `org.hibernate.annotations.Type` seems to be replaceable by a suitable JPA `@Converter`.

However, there are more usages of Hibernate in my code where I am struggling more:

- `org.hibernate.annotations.Immutable`
- `org.hibernate.annotations.OptimisticLock`
- `org.hibernate.annotations.DiscriminatorOptions`
- `org.hibernate.annotations.Fetch`
- `org.hibernate.EmptyInterceptor`

Could you give me any hints if and how those can be migrated to JPA? Alternatively, links to a Hibernate → JPA migration guide/tutorial would be very appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

You can't replace these unless you want to rewrite your application. You shouldn't try to avoid these annotations IMO as that would just leave you with a bad performing application that is probably still not portable. Hibernate is the de-facto JPA implementation, so I doubt you want to move away from it.